# Unable to update links to meeting workspaces in a calendar list

Tags: meeting-workspace, 2007

We have four meetings set up in workspace so that we can link from dates in the calendar. If you link from a meeting date to the wrong workspace and then edit to correct it, the link still remains in the wrong meeting workspace.

Has anyone any ideas how to delete this?

Answer (score 1):

Within the workspace, I think if you hover over the date from the list on the left hand side you can select to remove that date. This might only work if you first dissociate the event from the workspace through the calendar.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, unfortunately their are no options when I hover over the date even after de-linking the workspace

Comment: It might be because you still have list items in that redundant event's workspace? Clear out all lists (Except Series lists!) and see if you are able to remove the date... (best do this in a test environment first)

Comment: Also, there was a previous article posted here which is related: http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/2049/cant-remove-a-meeting-workspace-instance